# Ошибка syntax error.unexpected ';', expecting ']' при использовании виджета Menu

Tags: php, yii2

Первый раз использую виджет Menu на yii2. Вышла ошибка на 8-й строчке:

> ParseError syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']'

```
 1| <?php echo Menu::widget([
 2|       $menuItems = [
 3|            ['label' => 'Главная', 'url' => ['/site/index'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item', 'style' => 'padding-right:50px;']],
 4|            ['label' => 'О Нас', 'url' => ['/site/about'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item', 'style' => 'padding-right:50px;']],
 5|            ['label' => 'Контакты', 'url' => ['/site/contact'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item', 'style' => 'padding-right:50px;']],
 6|        ],
 7|        'items' => $menuItems,
 8|        'options' => ['class' => 'reset', 'role' => 'navigation'];
 9|        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
10|            $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Signup', 'url' => ['/site/signup'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item', 'style' => 'padding-right:50px;']];
11|             $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item']];
12|         } else {
13|             $menuItems[] = '<li>'
14|                 . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'], 'post')
15|                 . Html::submitButton(
16|                     'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
17|                     ['class' => 'btn btn-link logout']
18|                 )
19|                 . Html::endForm()
20|                 . '</li>';
21|             }
22|     ]); ?>
```

Comment: Добрый вечер. У Вас ошибка не только на восьмой строке, но и вообще, неверно Вы виджет настраиваете.

Comment: ещё лучше.. не могли бы вы помочь, что я не так настроила? наверное условие не правильно написано, так как я его взяла с navbar widget

Comment: Вы неверно используете массив для items

Comment: А где Вы именно брали условие с navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так настраивайте виджет. Не надо использовать форму ради одной ссылки "Logout". Достаточно правильно оформить ссылку и всё будет работать.

```
    <?php
$menuItems = array_filter([
    ['label' => 'Главная', 'url' => ['/site/index'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item', 'style' => 'padding-right:50px;']],
    ['label' => 'О Нас', 'url' => ['/site/about'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item', 'style' => 'padding-right:50px;']],
    ['label' => 'Контакты', 'url' => ['/site/contact'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item', 'style' => 'padding-right:50px;']],
    Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
        ['label' => 'Signup', 'url' => ['/site/signup'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item', 'style' => 'padding-right:50px;']]
        : false,
    Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
        ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item']]
        : false,
    !Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
        ['label' => 'Logout', 'url' => ['site/logout'], 'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']]
        : false
]);
echo Menu::widget([
    'items' => $menuItems,
    'options' => ['class' => 'reset', 'role' => 'navigation'],

]); ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное как я вам благодарна!!!!